# Как добавить кнопку в инпут? html

Tags: html

Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста.
Как в HTML добавить `<input type="button">` в `<input type="text">`, чтобы получилось как на фото?
Заранее спасибо.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
   .search {
    width: 300px; /* Ширина поля с кнопкой */
    border: 1px solid #000; /* Параметры рамки */
    min-height: 20px; /* Минимальная высота */
   }
   input[type="search"] {
    border: none; /* Убираем рамку */
    outline: none; /* Убираем свечение в Chrome и Safari */
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Убираем рамку в Chrome и Safari */
    width: 274px; /* Ширина поля */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Выравнивание по середине */
   }
   input[type="submit"] {
    width: 20px; /* Ширина кнопки */
    height: 20px; /* Высота кнопки */
    border: none; /* Убираем рамку */
    background: url(images/video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%; /* Параметры фона */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
    <div class="search">
     <input type="search" name="q">
     <input type="submit" value="">
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно такой вариант

```css
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      outline: none;
    }
    .wrapper_inpt {
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 2px;
    }
    .btn_area {
      width: 80px;
      height: 36px;
      background: #4ba025;
      border-radius: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 0.7em;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    input {
      border: none;
      background: none;
      width: calc(100% - 84px);
      height: 100%;
      text-indent: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper_inpt">
    <input type="text" placeholder="denis@getcraftwork.com">
    <div class="btn_area">
      Send Invite →
    </div>
  </div>
```